# Test Method is success in one org and failing in another org

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

I am running my test method in dev org which is successful but when I am running the same method in another org, I am getting error :

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
> a4Bc0000001meUQEAY; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
> WorkOrder: execution of BeforeUpdate
>
> caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to
> SObject
>
> (SVMXC): []
>
> Stack Trace   Class.EU_WorkOrderTest.testUpdateParentPMRejectedWO: line
> 3867, column 1

Totally confused with this. Below is the test method code. Please suggest.

```
public testMethod static void testUpdateParentPMRejectedWO() {
    Id recordTypeId_PM = Schema.SObjectType.SVMXC__Service_Order__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Preventative Maintenance').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtEUAcc = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('EU Account Record Type').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtEUSPAcc = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Service Provider').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtCon = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('EU Contact Record Type').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtSPCon = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('EU SP Contact Record Type').getRecordTypeId();
    Id rtInstalledAsset = Schema.SObjectType.SVMXC__Installed_Product__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('EU Record Type').getRecordTypeId();
    
    List<RTMap__c> lstRTMap = new List<RTMap__c>();
    RTMap__c rtMap1 = TestUtils.createRTMapForObject(recordTypeId_PM , 'SVMXC__Service_Order__c', 'EU', 'Preventative Maintenance', false);
    lstRTMap.add(rtMap1);
    insert lstRTMap;

    //insert Accout
    List<Account> lstAcc = new List<Account>();
    Account acc = new Account(Name='test account123',RecordTypeId = rtEUAcc, email__c = 'testemail123@noreply.com',BillingCity='test city',
    BillingCountry='Germany',BillingPostalCode='123490',BillingStreet='test street');
    lstAcc.add(acc);
    
    Account acc1 = new Account();
    acc1.RecordTypeId = rtEUSPAcc;
    acc1.Name = 'Test Account1';
    acc1.email__c = 'test1@test.com';
    acc1.Active__c = true;
    lstAcc.add(acc1);
    insert lstAcc;
    
    //insert contact
    List<Contact> lstCon = new List<Contact>();
    Contact con = new Contact(RecordTypeId = rtSPCon,FirstName = 'Test firstname1',LastName = 'test lastname1',Email='test@test1.com', AccountId=acc1.Id, Preferred_Language__c = 'English');
    lstCon.add(con);
    insert lstCon;
   //insert user
   UserRole r;
   List<User> lstUser = new List<User>();
   Profile p1 = [select Id,name from Profile where Name = 'EU Service Provider' limit 1];   
   r = new UserRole(DeveloperName = 'MyCustomRole', Name = 'EU Stryker Europe');            
   User euSPUser = new User(
               FirstName = 'test User1',
               UserRoleId = r.Id,
               profileId = p1.id,
               ContactId = lstCon[0].Id,
               username = 'newUser1@noreply.com',
               email = 'newuser1@noreply.com',
               emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
               localesidkey = 'en_US',
               languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
               timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
               alias='nuser1',
               lastname='lastname1',
               License_Allocation__c = 'Europe Field Service');
               lstUser.add(euSPUser);
   insert lstUser;

   //insert Technician Group
   SVMXC__Service_Group__c techgroup=new SVMXC__Service_Group__c();
   techgroup.Name='Tester group';
   techgroup.SVMXC__Active__c=true;
   insert techgroup;

   //insert technician
   List<SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c> lstTech = new List<SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c>();
   SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c tech=new SVMXC__Service_Group_Members__c();
   tech.Name='Tester';
   tech.SVMXC__Service_Group__c=techgroup.Id;
   tech.SVMXC__Email__c = 'testemail@noreply.com';
   tech.SVMXC__Salesforce_User__c = euSPUser.Id;
   tech.Business_Unit__c = 'EU';
   lstTech.add(tech);
   insert lstTech;
   
   //insert location
   List<SVMXC__Site__c> locationList=new List<SVMXC__Site__c>();
   SVMXC__Site__c location1 = new SVMXC__Site__c();
   location1.Name='Test Location1';
   location1.SVMXC__Country__c ='Germany' ;
   location1.RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.SVMXC__Site__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('External Location').getRecordTypeId();
   location1.SVMXC__Account__c = acc.Id;
   location1.Bill_To__c = true;
   locationList.add(location1);

   SVMXC__Site__c location2 = new SVMXC__Site__c();
   location2.Name='Test Location2';
   location2.SVMXC__Country__c ='Germany' ;
   location2.RecordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.SVMXC__Site__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('External Location').getRecordTypeId();
   location2.SVMXC__Account__c = acc.Id;
   location2.Ship_To__c = true;
   location2.Primary_Location__c = true;
   locationList.add(location2);
   insert locationList;
   
   //insert SLA Terms
   SVMXC__Service_Level__c termsSLA = new SVMXC__Service_Level__c();
   termsSLA.Name = 'Severity 4';
   termsSLA.Days_to_Close__c = 2;
   insert termsSLA;
   
   //insert product
   Product2 prd1 = new Product2(Name = 'Test Product Entry 1', Description = 'Test Product Entry 1', isActive = true, ProductCode = '1235');
   prd1.Business_Unit__c = 'EU';
   insert prd1;
  
   //insert Installed Assets
   SVMXC__Installed_Product__c assetItem = new SVMXC__Installed_Product__c();
   assetItem.Name = 'Test';
   assetItem.QIP_ID__c = 'QIP Visum Single LT';
   assetItem.SVMXC__Product__c = prd1.Id;
   assetItem.business_Unit__c = 'EU';
   assetItem.recordTypeId = rtInstalledAsset;
   insert assetItem;
   
   //insert Territory
   SVMXC__Territory__c ter = new SVMXC__Territory__c(Name = 'UK');
   insert ter;
   Test.startTest();
   //insert parent PM Work Order
   List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> objParentWO = TestUtils.createServiceOrder(recordTypeId_PM,1);
   insert objParentWO;
   objParentWO[0].Is_PM_Parent__c = true;
   objParentWO[0].Ship_To_Location__c = location2.id;
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Primary_Territory__c = ter.Id;
   objParentWO[0].Bill_To_Location__c = location1.id;
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Priority__c = 'Critical';
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Order_Status__c = 'open';
   objParentWO[0].Business_Unit__c = 'EU';
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Site__c = location2.ID;
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Company__c = lstAcc[0].id;
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Component__c = assetItem.Id;            
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Problem_Description__c = 'This is test data';    
   objParentWO[0].Language__c='English';
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__SLA_Terms__c= termsSLA.Id;
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Country__c='Germany';
   objParentWO[0].SVMXC__Group_Member__c=lstTech[0].Id;
   update objParentWO;
   //insert child PM work Order
   List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> objChildWO = TestUtils.createServiceOrder(recordTypeId_PM,1);
   insert objChildWO;
   objChildWO[0].Is_PM_Parent__c = false;
   objChildWO[0].Ship_To_Location__c = location2.id;
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Primary_Territory__c = ter.Id;
   objChildWO[0].Bill_To_Location__c = location1.id;
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Priority__c = 'Critical';
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Order_Status__c = 'open';
   objChildWO[0].Business_Unit__c = 'EU';
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Site__c = location2.ID;
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Company__c = lstAcc[0].id;
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Component__c = assetItem.Id;            
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Problem_Description__c = 'This is test data';    
   objChildWO[0].Language__c='English';
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__SLA_Terms__c= termsSLA.Id;
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Country__c='Germany';
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Group_Member__c=lstTech[0].Id;
   update objChildWO;
   
   objChildWO[0].SVMXC__Order_Status__c = 'Rejected';
   objChildWO[0].Work_Order_Quote__c = objParentWO[0].Id;
   update objChildWO; // this is where my code is failing in other org.
   List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> lstObjWO = [SELECT Id, SVMXC__Order_Status__c FROM SVMXC__Service_Order__c WHERE ID IN:objParentWO limit 1];
   system.assertEquals(lstObjWO[0].SVMXC__Order_Status__c, 'Rejected');
   Test.stopTest();
```

}

Comment: please check debug logs it will have more info. and  it might be due to license issue also.  do the user who is running test has necessary license and permissions  related to installed package and objects involved?

Comment: Which line is line 3867? About the only thing I could see failing (with that particular error) is `Profile p1 = [select Id,name from Profile where Name = 'EU Service Provider' limit 1];` If that is indeed the line that's failing, then the reason is simple. Either you don't have that profile in your other org, or it's named something different.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Can you try remove and add the lines List<SVMXC__Service_Order__c> lstObjWO = [SELECT Id, SVMXC__Order_Status__c FROM SVMXC__Service_Order__c WHERE ID IN:objParentWO limit 1];
   system.assertEquals(lstObjWO[0].SVMXC__Order_Status__c, 'Rejected'); after Test.stopTest()?

Comment: @redparrot The "no rows for assignment to SObject" error can't possibly be generated from those two lines. You only run into that error when you do something like `SObject = [query]`. The exception you'd get from `lstObjWO[0]` if the list were empty would be "List index out of bounds: 0".

Comment: @DerekF i have commented in code that this method is failing here.. update objWO.. before assert statement… please check once and advise

Comment: @DerekF  When I am using database.update instead of just update, it is working fine. Is it ok to use database.update or will it impact my test class in any way.

Comment: It's possible that the error is being thrown by your ServiceMax Core managed package as it's trying to run a query when you update their custom object record.  You should check the ServiceMax Core configuration in the other org, and also check their support and documentation resources.